# nodejs mssql driver passing integers throws errors

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express

Using the NodeJs mssql driver from npm, and I'm passing data back to the database, and I have the object built properly, and I've tried to make sure that any int fields, I get an 'Incorrect syntax near "int field"' error.

Using the mssql driver, how do I properly pass integer values? I'm also using string template syntax in my calls. Here is an example call to the driver:

```
  return mssql.connect(sqlConfig).then(()=> {
    return new mssql.Request()
                    .query(`insert into nameInfo (nameInfoId, firstName, prefName, lastName, suffix, alreadyCorrect, updatedDate, updated, correctPerson) values ${name.IndivId}, ${name.firstName}, ${name.prefName}, ${name.lastName}, ${name.suffix}, ${ac},${Date.now()}, 1,${cp}`)
                    .then(response => {
                      console.log(record);
                      mssql.close();
                      return record;
                    }).catch((err) =>{
                      console.error(err);
                      mssql.close();
                    });
  });
```

Comment: Missing parenthesis after `values` clause `Insert into..values (val1,val2,..)`

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to put the strings inside single quote and put the values inside the parenthesis 
Just like this

```
return mssql.connect(sqlConfig).then(()=> {
    return new mssql.Request()
                    .query(`insert into nameInfo (nameInfoId, firstName, prefName, lastName, suffix, alreadyCorrect, updatedDate, updated, correctPerson) values (${name.IndivId}, '${name.firstName}', '${name.prefName}', '${name.lastName}', '${name.suffix}', '${ac}','${Date.now()}', 1,'${cp}')`)
                    .then(response => {
                      console.log(record);
                      mssql.close();
                      return record;
                    }).catch((err) =>{
                      console.error(err);
                      mssql.close();
                    });
  });
```